# How to get message embed info using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I tried to get embed field for something but I can't find how thats what I tried

Hi

I'm trying to get info on embed message with discord.js

the variable message I'm getting from the `message` event

Example:

```
message.embeds.MessageEmbed.type // Error
message.embeds.type // undefined
```

Like you saw in the example I'm getting Error and undefined results
How can I get the info from the embed correctly.

Thank You For Your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`message.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds) returns a `Array` of every [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) in the message. You can use `message.embeds[0]` to get the first embed. [`MessageEmbed.fields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=fields) *also* returns an `Array` of every field within the embed.

```js
message.embeds[0].fields

// example:
[{
 name: 'Level',
 value: '5',
 inline: false,
},
 name: 'Username',
 value: 'Lioness100',
 inline: false,
}];
```